# Import solution and enable "any SDK messages processes steps"

Tags: c#, deployment, dynamics-crm-2011, solution

I'm working on an import tool for Dynamics CRM.
I can import solutions but when there are plugins in it (SDK Messages Processes Steps), they're all disabled.

During a web deployment, I just need to check the box :
[image: enable any SDK messages processes steps]

But I can't find anything to do so programmatically.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property `PublishWorkflows` to `true`

```
ImportSolutionRequest request = new ImportSolutionRequest();
request.PublishWorkflows = true;
```

Comment: I'm not sure is that, because the description for "Publish Workflows" speaks about "processes (workflows)". I'm looking for "SDK Messages Processes Steps". But I will give it a try anyway ;)

Comment: This check box refers to both workflows and SdkMessageProcessSteps